# How to calculate the inverse route (A -> B and B -> A)?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My code calculates the distance and duration between source and destination (A -> B). I would like to include in the same calculating the inverse route (B -> A).

I need to click the "Calc" button to calculate the total distance (A-> B) + (B-> A).

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var campos_max = 8; 
            var x = 1; 
            $('#add_field').click (function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();     //prevent new clicks
                    if (x < campos_max) {
                            $('#lists').append('<div class="divLista">\
                                    <td width="80">Point 0'+ x +': </td><td width="150"><input type="text" placeholder="Point 0'+ x +'" class="points" id="waypoint'+ x +'"> <input type="button" value="-" class="remove_campo"></td></div>');
                                    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('waypoint'+ x)),{types: ['geocode']});
                            x++;
                    }
            });

            // Remove div
            $('#lists').on("click",".remove_campo",function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parent('div').remove();
                    x--;
            });
    });
    
    var directionDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;
    var source, destination;
    var directionsDisplay;

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
            new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
            new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
    });
        
    
    function initialize() {
      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(40.659036, -73.937796);
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: chicago
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), myOptions);
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function calcRoute() {
    
        source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
        destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;
      
            var elem = document.getElementsByClassName( 'points' );
            var wayPoints = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; ++i) {
                if (typeof elem[i].attributes.class !== "undfined") {
                    if(elem[i].attributes.class.value === "points"){
                        wayPoints.push({
                        location: elem[i].value,
                        stopover: true
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            
            var request = {
                origin: source,
                destination: destination,
                waypoints: wayPoints,
                optimizeWaypoints: true,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          var route = response.routes[0];
          // For each route, display summary information.
          for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
            var routeSegment = i + 1;   
          }
          computeTotalDistance(response);
        } else {
        }
      });
    }

    function computeTotalDistance(result) {
      var totalDist = 0;
      var totalTime = 0;
      var myroute = result.routes[0];
      for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        totalDist += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
        totalTime += myroute.legs[i].duration.value;
      }
      totalDist = totalDist / 1000.
                    
        var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
        dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
    
        function timeConvert(time) { 
            seconds = time;
            minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
            hours = Math.floor(minutes/60);
            days = Math.floor(hours/24);
            hours = hours-(days*24);
            minutes = minutes-(days*24*60)-(hours*60);
            seconds = seconds-(days*24*60*60)-(hours*60*60)-(minutes*60);
            return (days>0?days + " dia ":"")  + (hours>0?hours + " h ":"") + (minutes>0?minutes + " min":"");
        }
    
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Distance: " + totalDist.toFixed(1).replace('.',',') + " km<br>Time: " + timeConvert(totalTime); 
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    margin:0;
    font-family:"Segoe UI","Lucida Grande",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    height:100%;

}
.painelLateral{
    float:left;
    width:350px;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
.dvMap{
    float:right;
    width:calc(100% - 350px);
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

.divLista{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<div class="painelLateral">
<form id="painel" name="painel">
  <table width="350" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="102">Source:</td>
      <td width="210"><input type="text" placeholder="Source" id="txtSource" style="width: 200px" /></td>
      <td width="72">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
        <tr></tr>
      </table >
        <div id="lists" align="right"></div></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="add_field" value="+" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Destination:</td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Destination" id="txtDestination"  style="width: 200px" /></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="Calc" onclick="calcRoute();" /></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    <div id="dvDistance"></div>
    <div id="directions_panel"></div>
    <div id="total"></div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="dvMap" id="dvMap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add some detail about what you've tried, and why it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already got point A->B working, why not move the piece of code that calculates the distance to its own function and convert source & destination to function arguments.

```
    function distanceService{source,destination)
    {
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [source],
            destinations: [destination],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, 

        function (response, status) {
         .......
        });

     return service;
    }
```

Then you can use it:

```
distanceService(A,B); or distanceService(B,A);
```

By doing this you will be able to build your service dynamically, switch A->B to B->A, get access to the distance variable and perform calculations on the resulting objects.

Comment: Hello EdMore, thank you very much for the response, as the update made the changes, but the first time I click "Calc" does not work, it only works on the second click. Would you help me?

I'm sorry, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `source` and `destination` to the start/end point (point A) set a waypoint at the destination point (point B).  The result will then be the desired result.

```
var request = {
  origin: source,
  destination: source,
  waypoints: [{location: destination, stopover: true}],
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/eyb6jcav/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var options = {
  componentRestrictions: {
    country: 'br'
  }
};
var source, destination;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService;
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtSource'), options);
  new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtDestination'), options);
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    'draggable': true
  });
});

var mumbai = new google.maps.LatLng(40.659036, -73.937796);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 5,
  center: mumbai
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);


function GetRoute() {
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  //directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));

  //*********DIRECTIONS AND ROUTES**********************//
  source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
  destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;


  var request = {
    origin: source,
    destination: source,
    waypoints: [{
      location: destination,
      stopover: true
    }],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });

  //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix({
      origins: [source],
      destinations: [destination],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    },

    function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
        var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
        var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
        var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
        dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
        dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
        dvDistance.innerHTML += "Duration:" + duration + "<br />";

      } else {
        alert("Could not trace this route.");
      }
    });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      Source:
      <input type="text" id="txtSource" style="width: 200px" />
      <br/> Destination:
      <input type="text" id="txtDestination" style="width: 200px" />
      <br />
      <input type="button" value="Calc" onclick="GetRoute()" />
      <hr />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div id="dvDistance">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="dvPanel" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello Geocode, thank you very much for the answer, but I will work with waypoints, and I think this solution would not be appropriate in this case. Is there any way I can change the Origin and Destination after the already mounted directions service?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your actual problem in the question itself. The posted code doesn't include any waypoints.

Comment: Hi Geocode, I updated to the actual code, as you can see I have Origin and Destination and Dynamic Waypoints, I need to calculate the round trip in a single result. Thank you!

Comment: What issues are you having making the reverse request and adding the resulting distance to the forward request?